# Sum of products of two arrays (dotproduct)

Tags: c#, arrays, math

First off, I know my title can be formulated better, but my math classes are so far gone I can't remember the correct words anymore..

I need to do something like this (pseudo c#)

```
int[] digits1 = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int[] digits2 = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int result = digits1*digits2
```

This would be the sum of the product of element[i] of each array.

This obviously doesn't work.
Any suggestions towards either a better title or the solution?

**EDIT**
clarification: I know I could loop them both and do the math.
Basically I would think there is a better way to do this and I'm looking for it purely out of personal curiousity.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're talking about `(0*0) + (1*1) + (2*2) + ...` right?

Comment: FYI, the type of product you seem to desire is called the dot product: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Answer (score 41, accepted):

With LINQ:

```
int dotProduct = digits1.Zip(digits2, (d1, d2) => d1 * d2)
                        .Sum();
```

`Zip`will produce a streaming sequence containing the products of corresponding elements from both arrays, which is then summed into an integer with `Sum`.

Note that this will not fail like it should when the arrays of unequal length, so you probably need to validate the input:

```
//null checks here

if(digits1.Length != digits2.Length)
   throw new ArgumentException("...");
```

EDIT:
As Jeff M points out,`Enumerable.Zip`was only added to the framework in .NET 4.0. In .NET 3.5, you can do this (the idea is only efficient for collections that expose fast indexers):

```
int dotProduct = Enumerable.Range(0, digits1.Length)
                           .Sum(i => digits1[i] * digits2[i]);

//from Jeff M's comment:
int dotProduct = digits1.Select((n, i) => n * digits2[i])
                        .Sum();
```

Answer (score 12):

Solutions with LINQ

```
int[] digits1 = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int[] digits2 = new int[10]{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

int result1 = digits1.Zip(digits2, (x, y) => x * y).Sum();

int result2 = digits1.Select((x, y) => x * digits2.ElementAt(y)).Sum();

int result3 = digits1.Select((n, i) => n * digits2[i]).Sum();

// Ani answer
int result4 = Enumerable.Range(0, digits1.Length)
    .Sum(i => digits1[i] * digits2[i]);
```

**Performance test** `100000` iterations:

```
Queries
Fn: Result 1       Ticks 135306
Fn: Result 2       Ticks 2470614
Fn: Result 3       Ticks 130034
Fn: Result 4       Ticks 123374

-------------

Fastest
Fn: Result 4       Ticks 123374
Fn: Result 3       Ticks 130034
Fn: Result 1       Ticks 135306
Fn: Result 2       Ticks 2470614
```

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks. I wonder where the diff from 2 comes from.

Answer (score 9):

I wrote a test bench to compare the these methods' times on my machine.

Specs:
Windows 7 Professional 64-bit
Intel Core 2 Quad Q9550 @ 2.83GHz
4x1GiB Corsair Dominator DDR2 1066 (PC2-8500)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Testbench
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var digits1 = Enumerable.Range(0, 500).ToArray();
            var digits2 = digits1.ToArray(); // create a copy

            Test("Regular Loop", () =>
            {
                int result = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < digits1.Length; i++)
                {
                    result += digits1[i] * digits2[i];
                }
                return result;
            });

            // using LINQ
            Test("Enumerable \"Loop\"", () => Enumerable.Range(0, digits1.Length).Sum(i => digits1[i] * digits2[i]));
            Test("Using Zip", () => digits1.Zip(digits2, (x, y) => x * y).Sum());
            Test("Using Indexed Select", () => digits1.Select((n, i) => n * digits2[i]).Sum());
            Test("Using Indexed Select with ElementAt", () => digits1.Select((n, i) => n * digits2.ElementAt(i)).Sum());

            // using PLINQ
            Test("Parallel Enumerable \"Loop\"", () => ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, digits1.Length).Sum(i => digits1[i] * digits2[i]));
            Test("Using Parallel Zip", () => digits1.AsParallel().Zip(digits2.AsParallel(), (x, y) => x * y).Sum());
            Test("Using Parallel Indexed Select", () => digits1.AsParallel().Select((n, i) => n * digits2[i]).Sum());
            Test("Using Parallel Indexed Select with ElementAt", () => digits1.AsParallel().Select((n, i) => n * digits2.ElementAt(i)).Sum());

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        static void Test<T>(string testName, Func<T> test, int iterations = 1000000)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(testName);
            Console.WriteLine("Iterations: {0}", iterations);
            var results = Enumerable.Repeat(0, iterations).Select(i => new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch()).ToList();
            var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
            {
                results[i].Start();
                test();
                results[i].Stop();
            }
            timer.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time(ms): {0,3}/{1,10}/{2,8} ({3,10})", results.Min(t => t.ElapsedMilliseconds), results.Average(t => t.ElapsedMilliseconds), results.Max(t => t.ElapsedMilliseconds), timer.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Console.WriteLine("Ticks:    {0,3}/{1,10}/{2,8} ({3,10})", results.Min(t => t.ElapsedTicks), results.Average(t => t.ElapsedTicks), results.Max(t => t.ElapsedTicks), timer.ElapsedTicks);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

**32-bit target:**

```
Regular Loop
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/         0/       0 (      1172)
Ticks:      3/  3.101365/     526 (   3244251)

Enumerable "Loop"
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   4.3E-05/      25 (      9054)
Ticks:     24/  24.93989/   69441 (  25052172)

Using Zip
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   2.4E-05/      16 (     16282)
Ticks:     41/ 44.941406/   45395 (  45052491)

Using Indexed Select
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   5.3E-05/      32 (     13473)
Ticks:     34/ 37.165088/   89602 (  37280177)

Using Indexed Select with ElementAt
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   1.5E-05/       6 (    160215)
Ticks:    405/443.154147/   17821 ( 443306156)

Parallel Enumerable "Loop"
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/  0.000103/      29 (     17194)
Ticks:     38/ 47.412312/   81906 (  47576133)

Using Parallel Zip
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   9.4E-05/      19 (     21703)
Ticks:     49/ 59.859005/   53200 (  60051081)

Using Parallel Indexed Select
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/  0.000114/      27 (     20579)
Ticks:     45/ 56.758491/   75455 (  56943627)

Using Parallel Indexed Select with ElementAt
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   8.1E-05/      19 (     61137)
Ticks:    144/ 168.97909/   53320 ( 169165086)
```

**64-bit target:**

```
Regular Loop
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/         0/       0 (       506)
Ticks:      1/  1.254137/    1491 (   1401969)

Enumerable "Loop"
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   2.9E-05/      15 (     10118)
Ticks:     27/ 27.850086/   41954 (  27995994)

Using Zip
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   2.2E-05/      13 (     17089)
Ticks:     45/ 47.132834/   38506 (  47284608)

Using Indexed Select
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   3.1E-05/      12 (     14057)
Ticks:     37/ 38.740923/   33846 (  38897274)

Using Indexed Select with ElementAt
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   3.8E-05/      29 (    117412)
Ticks:    304/324.711279/   82726 ( 324872753)

Parallel Enumerable "Loop"
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   9.9E-05/      28 (     24234)
Ticks:     38/  66.79389/   77578 (  67054956)

Using Parallel Zip
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/  0.000111/      24 (     30193)
Ticks:     46/ 83.264037/   69029 (  83542711)

Using Parallel Indexed Select
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   6.5E-05/      20 (     28417)
Ticks:     45/ 78.337831/   56354 (  78628396)

Using Parallel Indexed Select with ElementAt
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/   9.2E-05/      16 (     65233)
Ticks:    112/180.154663/   44799 ( 180496754)
```

Comment: Wow, I figured the loop would be faster, but not by that much.  The LINQ methods are definitely shorter and arguable simpler to write, but create a lot of overhead.  Thanks for running the test.

Comment: Wouldn't the linq methods be faster in a multi threading scenario?

Comment: @boris: No it wouldn't.  While there are optimization opportunities, it will only use a single thread.  If changed to use PLINQ, then yes definitely.  I'll make modifications to include them and repost my results.

Comment: @boris: I said "yes definitely," it does have some caveats.  If the arrays were sufficiently large, then "yes definitely."  Otherwise, it's unnecessary overhead and might not benefit.

Comment: @boris: I'll be updating one more time.  (I need to find a better way to measure the times)  Restructuring the test function improved the times all around (due to an overhead I didn't anticipate).  The numbers are more reasonable.

Comment: Wow. Thanks for all the effort. It seems the regular for loop still is more interesting for my scenario.

Answer (score 8):

Very simply, do a loop.

```
int sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < digits1.length && i < digits2.length; i++)
{
    sum += digits1[i] * digits2[i];
}
```

Boom.

Answer (score 4):

```
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < digits1.length; i++)
{
    result += digits1[i] * digits2[i];
}
```

Comment: Well yes, but isn't there a better algorithm for this?

Comment: I don't think so, you need to do at least n multiplications and n additions, and this does that.  I believe it is the least amount of work possible.  There may be ways to do it with less code, but the work the code does will be the same.

Comment: Well looks like there is a better way to do it, its been too long since I have done C#.  But I believe the runtime should be similar for Zip and the loop since the same work needs to be done.

Comment: I agree with the above. The short, fancy ways of doing this work, and they're concise, but they may not be as clear to someone else reading the code later.

Comment: Mathematically you are right, but I would think an average processor would have optimizations for working with arrays (matrices) that could be used by the .net framework. I know it is optimization circus, but I'm looking into this purely out of curiosity.

Comment: Can someone run a performance test? @BrunoLM ran one for the LINQ solutions, but I would be interested to compare it to the loop and I do not have a C# environment available right now.

Comment: @Alan: I ran a test.  [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3992363/sum-of-products-of-two-arrays-dotproduct/3992840#3992840)

Comment: Just because you *can* do it with LINQ doesn't mean you have to. I prefer loops because it is more readable in this case. In fact you can make a static method, or an extension method called `Dot` and that would make the code even _more_ readable.

Comment: This **is** the best. Easily translatable into any other language and with best performance since linq gives you some overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Even faster is to unroll the loop

```
Test("Regular Loop", () =>
            {
                int result = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < digits1.Length; i++)
                {
                    result += digits1[i] * digits2[i];
                }
                return result;
            });
            // This will fail if vectors are not a multiple of 4 in length.
            Test("Unroll 4x", () =>
            {
                int result = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < digits1.Length; i+=4)
                {
                    result += digits1[i] * digits2[i];
                    result += digits1[i+1] * digits2[i+1];
                    result += digits1[i+2] * digits2[i+2];
                    result += digits1[i+3] * digits2[i+3];
                }
                return result;
            });

            Test("Dynamic unroll", () =>
            {
                int result = 0;
                int limit = (digits1.Length/8)*8;
                int reminderLimit = digits1.Length;

                if (digits1.Length >= 8)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i+=8)
                    {
                        result += digits1[i] * digits2[i];
                        result += digits1[i+1] * digits2[i+1];
                        result += digits1[i+2] * digits2[i+2];
                        result += digits1[i+3] * digits2[i+3];
                        result += digits1[i+4] * digits2[i+4];
                        result += digits1[i+5] * digits2[i+5];
                        result += digits1[i+6] * digits2[i+6];
                        result += digits1[i+7] * digits2[i+7];
                    }

                    reminderLimit = digits1.Length % 8;
                }

                switch(reminderLimit)
                {
                    case 7: {
                                result += digits1[limit] * digits2[limit];
                                result += digits1[limit+1] * digits2[limit+1];
                                result += digits1[limit+2] * digits2[limit+2];
                                result += digits1[limit+3] * digits2[limit+3];
                                result += digits1[limit+4] * digits2[limit+4];
                                result += digits1[limit+5] * digits2[limit+5];
                                result += digits1[limit+6] * digits2[limit+6];
                                break;
                            }

                    case 6: {
                                result += digits1[limit] * digits2[limit];
                                result += digits1[limit+1] * digits2[limit+1];
                                result += digits1[limit+2] * digits2[limit+2];
                                result += digits1[limit+3] * digits2[limit+3];
                                result += digits1[limit+4] * digits2[limit+4];
                                result += digits1[limit+5] * digits2[limit+5];      
                                break;
                            }

                    case 5: {
                                result += digits1[limit] * digits2[limit];
                                result += digits1[limit+1] * digits2[limit+1];
                                result += digits1[limit+2] * digits2[limit+2];
                                result += digits1[limit+3] * digits2[limit+3];
                                result += digits1[limit+4] * digits2[limit+4];
                                break;
                            }

                    case 4: {
                                result += digits1[limit] * digits2[limit];
                                result += digits1[limit+1] * digits2[limit+1];
                                result += digits1[limit+2] * digits2[limit+2];
                                result += digits1[limit+3] * digits2[limit+3];
                                break;
                            }

                    case 3: {
                                result += digits1[limit] * digits2[limit];
                                result += digits1[limit+1] * digits2[limit+1];
                                result += digits1[limit+2] * digits2[limit+2];
                                break;
                            }

                    case 2: {
                                result += digits1[limit] * digits2[limit];
                                result += digits1[limit+1] * digits2[limit+1];
                                break;
                            }

                    case 1: {
                                result += digits1[limit] * digits2[limit];
                                break;
                            }
                    default :
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                }

                return result;
            });
```

There is a huge difference is running time between debug and release mode of C# code, this is run with release mode:

```
Regular Loop
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/         0/       0 (       596)
Ticks:      1/  2,071213/     455 (   2154248)

Unroll 4x
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/     2E-06/       1 (       575)
Ticks:      1/  1,984301/    3876 (   2076105)

Dynamic unroll
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/         0/       0 (       430)
Ticks:      1/    1,4635/    3228 (   1554830)
```

Debug mode:

```
Regular Loop
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/     1E-06/       1 (      1296)
Ticks:      4/  4,529916/    3907 (   4678354)

Unroll 4x
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/         0/       0 (       871)
Ticks:      2/  3,048466/     701 (   3145277)

Dynamic unroll
Iterations: 1000000
Time(ms):   0/         0/       0 (       819)
Ticks:      2/  2,858588/    1398 (   2957179)
```

Comment: Am I reading the results correctly that in Release the best case difference is 160ms for 1M iterations? Seems like a nice optimization for a super niche situation, but wouldn't recommend this as a go-to solution :)